# Magento 2.1 : How to remove copyright from within the Admin panel (in the footer)?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin-panel, footer, copyright

How would one change the Copyright in the Admin panel? Just to clarify - I'm speaking about the copyright notice on the bottom of the page inside the admin panel and on the login page into the admin panel.

Magento 2.1.0

Answer (score 7):

Do not know what is the purpose for modification.

You can modify this text in below template.(recommended by creating new module)

/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Copyright&copy; %1 Magento Commerce Inc. All rights reserved.', date('Y')) ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the template file isn't the best practice though. The admin legal blocks are defined in:
/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml:55

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <container name="legal" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-legal">
        <container name="legal.copyright" htmlTag="p" htmlClass="copyright col-m-6">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Copyright" name="copyright" as="copyright" />
        </container>
        <container name="legal.system" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-legal-system col-m-6">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Footer" name="version" as="version" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report" as="report" template="Magento_Backend::page/report.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="bugreport_url" xsi:type="string">https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

So, if you want to remove the whole thing, including the version and bug report url, you could add this in any layout update file that is active on all admin pages:

```
<referenceContainer name="copyright" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove copy rights and Magento version etc., on admin panel footer section.

You can change by using custom module. Please follow the below steps

Step 1: Create `default.xml`  file  like in below path

```
app/code/Vendor/Customtheme/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
```

Step 2: Add below code to remove footer sections contents

```
<referenceContainer name="legal" remove="true"/>
```

After running the below command and provide file permission

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the file

`BlockquoteOverriding` the template file isn't the best practice though. The admin legal blocks are defined in:

```
/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml:55
Blockquote
```

but I could not find a place to insert the code `<referenceContainer name="legal" remove="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the copyright block from layout file..

Please add following code to your **default.xml** file and check after cache clean.